# Why does dotnet vstest return "No test is available in" when the test works in vstest.console.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version, vstest

I have a built dll file for a test project in .net framework 4.6.

The test runs fine when I do `vstest.console.exe test.dll` but when I do `dotnet vstest test.dll` it says

> No test is available in test.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I want to run coverlet on the dll but it seems like that won't work until I get `dotnet vstest` to work.

Answer (score 9):

I was sort of able to reproduce your problem, though in my case I could not get *either* `vstest.console.exe test.dll` or `dotnet vstest test.dll` to work. they both just spat out the same error about no tests being available.

Issue reproduction:

- Use NUnit as the testing framework.

Fix:

1. Add a reference to `Nunit3TestAdapter` in `packages.config`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="NUnit" version="3.12.0" targetFramework="net46" />
      <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.16.1" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
    </packages>
```

2. Rebuild the solution.

Then both of the commands `vstest.console.exe test.dll` and `dotnet vstest test.dll` worked as expected.

---

If you are using a different testing framework than NUnit, there ought to be a corresponding adapter to serve the same purpose.

I have verified that this works for MSTest as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Comment: We are using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Comment: @agentq15 that namespace belongs to the MSTest.TestFramework nuget package, whose corresponding adapter is MSTest.TestAdapter, so try that. i have verified that they work in tandem the same as NUnit in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding this adapter parameter (`-a` and path to the test adapter from the solution folder) in command and it worked:

```
dotnet test -a "..\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.4.0.0\build\net35" --logger "trx;LogFileName=TestResults.trx" "..\bin\Debug\project.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a generic method in your test class and remove it or move it somewhere else. This seems to break the tests.